# When to use Properties and when Map in Java?

Tags: java

Difference between Map and Properties as both have key-value pair.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A map is meant for normal key-value pair usage in code.  Properties are typically used for storing and loading configuration values from a file.  The underlying implementation of a Properties uses a Map.

See the link below for a quick tutorial on how and when to use Properties.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

Answer (score 12):

`Properties` is a [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) for `Map<String,String>` + some I/O methods.

Do you need the I/O methods ? use it : don't.

Answer (score 2):

Use a class that's implementing the Map interface, but isn't the Properties class. The Properties class is broken. Since it's a Hashtable underneath, there are methods that would break the otherwise consistent String-to-String mapping. Its invariant is very easily broken (both mistakenly and on purpose). Use anything else implementing the Map interface. If you're aiming for thread safety - use Collections.synchronizedMap(myUnsyncdMap) to create one.

Ideally, there is no difference between the two classes other than 1 or two methods mentioned in the other answers. However the Properties implementation is actually bizarre - other classes, deriving from the Map interface, are much safer, provide better statical typing and are probably faster (depending on what you need). Taking a quick look at the implementation (specifically which class it derives from) should be enough to convince you to avoid it :)

Answer (score 1):

The Properties Class implements the Map-Interface.
The Properties Class has Methods to save its content to a Stream.

look at: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

If you do not need to save the content, stay with a "normal" Map Implementation like HashMap

Answer (score 1):

A **per key default system** is another feature of `Properties` not present in `Hashtable` is . E.g.:

```
Properties p0 = new Properties();
p0.setProperty("a", "0");
p0.setProperty("b", "1");
Properties p1 = new Properties(p0);
p1.setProperty("a", "10");
assert p1.getProperty("a").equals("10");
assert p1.getProperty("b").equals("1");
assert p1.getProperty("c") == null;
```

Defaults are searched recursively in parent properties.

Comment: Interesting point, but note that if you replace `Properties` with `Hashtable` (and `getProperty` with `get`) in the example the result will be the same. However, move construction of `p1` before the `setProperty` calls on `p0` and the reference vs copy semantics will become clear.  HOWEVER, calling `get` rather than `getProperty` will bypass this default value behavior of `Properties`.

Answer (score 0):

Properties is mainly used for  based configuration data and localization, while Map is more general-purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A Properties object *is a* Map. See for example http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html. I.e. the Properties class implements the Map interface.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs,

- [Map](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is an interface
- [Properties](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) is a class that implements that interface

Answer (score 0):

Properties IS-A Map which IS-A Hashtable.  Whether it should or not is a different question - I think it should really get the Map through composition and not implementing the Map interface.

Properties class is for Properties files - that's why it has load methods on it to read the file in.  So if you're working with properties files e.g.

```
propa = bob
propb = jane
```

then use Properties.  Otherwise you'll want to create your own Map interface and pick an appropiate implementation e.g. HashMap

Comment: Retification: Properties IS-A Hashtable which IS-A Map.