# What is the difference between a Hashtable and Properties?

Tags: java

What is the difference between a Hashtable and Properties?

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977125/when-to-use-properties-and-when-map-in-java

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`Properties`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) is a very specialized class that's designed to hold configuration and/or resources that are usually stored in some file.

It has several features that `Hashtable` doesn't have (and shouldn't have):

- It supports reading and writing its content to a well-defined plain-text format (using [`load()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream))/[`store()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String)))
- It supports reading and writing its content to a well-defined XML-based format (using [`loadFromXML()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML(java.io.InputStream))/[`storeToXML()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#storeToXML(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String)))
- It supports a default mechanism [by providing another `Properties` instance at construction time](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#Properties(java.util.Properties)).
- It only supports `String` keys and values. While it is technically a `Map<Object,Object>` actually storing non-`String` keys or values is strongly discouraged and unsupported.

A [`Hashtable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) on the other hand is a general-purpose [`Map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implementation (which is mostly replaced by the [`HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), however).

Comment: It only supports String keys and values. While it is technically a Map<Object,Object> actually storing non-String keys or values is strongly discouraged and unsupported.... unsupported in what way if Object keys are allowed?

Answer (score 6):

Properties is a subclass of Hashtable, and it is designed for string to string mappings. It also adds the ability to store the mapping into a text file, and read it back.

Answer (score 0):

1.Properties is the **subclass of Hashtable**. It is more like a map which stores key value pair.

2.In properties both key and value are string

3.In properties we can store the key and value pair in a properties file .

4.Properties class has the **ability to load and save the properties file** while Hashtable doesn't have this method.

5.Properties files are mostly used to **store configuration or localization** data. They are used to externalize the data which is configurable to the application.